# Anaconda 3 on Windows 10 cannot install pyinstaller - ssl certificate problem

Tags: pip, anaconda, pyinstaller

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyinstaller/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyinstaller/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyinstaller pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the following files

libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*
from D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.

And it works as a charm!