# Could Not Fetch URL: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

```
['C:\\Users\\pt\\miniconda3\\envs\\ldo\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\stable-diffusion-main\\condaenv.2dun9wid.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/albumentations/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/albumentations/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/albumentations/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/albumentations/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/albumentations/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/albumentations/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/albumentations/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement albumentations==0.4.3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for albumentations==0.4.3
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

I have tried creating a pip.ini under /ProgramData/pip/pip.ini

I have tried [Anaconda 3 on Windows 10 cannot install pyinstaller - ssl certificate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959564/anaconda-3-on-windows-10-cannot-install-pyinstaller-ssl-certificate-problem)

Neither of these solutions work. I'm out of ideas

Edit: I've tried installing the OpenSSL library that a comment poster made, but that doesn't work either.
The weird thing is when I fresh install miniconda it works for a bit then fails with the same error I get above.

Comment: Message `however the ssl module in Python is not available.` can means it need to install C/C++ library [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/). You have to download it manually, and install it manually: [ssl - How to install OpenSSL in windows 10? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I've tried that - I've installed 3.0.5 the latest version and set it via the PATH settings.